# Matlab code for albeit series plotting

Tags: matlab

I need a help to plot this equation in MATLAB.

```
sin((2*m+1)*pi*x)/((2*m+1)^3)*(1- ((cosh((2*m+1)*pi*(0.25-0.5)))/cosh((2*m+1)*0.5*pi)))
```

`m` goes from `0` to `infinity` and `x` varies between `0` and `1`. I tried it using this code but getting an error as inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Use element-wise operations: replace `*` with `.*` and `/` with `./`

Comment: Your solution worked for my code. Thank you so much.